# Is it possible to manage my multiple accounts and my wife's multiple accounts as a single portfolio with TD Ameritrade?

Tags: mutual-funds, online-tools, asset-allocation, portfolio, asset-class

Is it possible to manage my multiple accounts and my wife's multiple accounts as a single portfolio with TD Ameritrade's online tools? I would like to do easy asset allocation across all those accounts include a percentage breakdown of holdings and asset classes.

She has several IRAs and I have several IRAs and a brokerage account. The rep tells me yes, but I heard there may be some legal restrictions on this. A (blacked out) screenshot would be appreciated! Thanks, Chirag

Comment: IRA = **Individual** Retirement Account.  You cannot operate your wife's IRA accounts.  I won't say Period because your wife may be able to give you a Power of Attorney document that her IRA custodian will accept and allow you to operate her IRA account, but that's a matter between her and her IRA custodian and the IRA agreement.  That being said, if she gives you her login ID and her password, you could operate her IRA account on the IRA custodian's web site without the IRA custodian knowing about it. Going through Ameritrade will add yet another layer of permissions for all this to occur.

Comment: @DilipSarwate "Trading Authorization" is a weaker form of consent that is often possible, and it permits somebody to trade on behalf of another person's account. I've seen this work before, and without having to use that person's own login ID and password.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea This is a question of trading on an IRA account which is quite different from a ordinary investment account. If OP Chirag's wife has an IRA invested in one Vanguard mutual fund, will Vanguard Fiduciary Trust Co allow him to transfer money into another Vanguard mutual fund (still part of his wife's IRA) while operating through a TD account? My gut feeling is that it is going to take a *lot* of effort and paperwork to make it happen.

Comment: @DilipSarwate It's two pages of paperwork, processed one time.  See https://www.tdameritrade.com/forms/TDA073.pdf (fixed link).. looks very similar to what we have in Canada.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oops, innocent copy/paste of wrong nearby link.   See corrected link just above.  My bad.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TD Ameritrade has a feature called "Link Accounts" that lets you manage all of your accounts from a single login.  It's been a while since I did it, but I believe you send a link request from your primary account to all of the other accounts you want to link, and then go into the other accounts to approve that.  I've got my account, my wife's Roth IRA, and my kids' ESA accounts all linked this way.  In the Balances and Positions section, you can view either an individual account, or all accounts combined.  It's pretty handy, and not that hard to set up.  I'm not sure if it will give you everything you're asking for, but it's at least part way down that road.